# UIAlertView crashes when inside a block

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview, objective-c-blocks

I have a block with a UIAlertView, and I would like to run some code once OK has been clicked.

```
- (IBAction)connectToAccount:(UIButton *)sender {


        void (^block) (FTjsonRecords *obj, NSError *error) = ^(FTjsonRecords *obj, NSError *error) {


                [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.hostReachability];

                    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!"
                                                                 message:@"Online sync is now enabled."
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [av show];


        };

        [sync checkFirstLogin:email viaPassword:password viaCompletion:block];
    }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:IOS_SWITCH_TAB object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];
}
```

The moment I click on OK, the app crashes without any exception to follow up. 
I am not sure how to proceed. An advice would be great. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I have set a break point right on `[av show];` and the thread looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Is that block executed on the main queue/thread?

Comment: @Scott I believe it is. Please see the updated question. Thanks

Comment: Is the completion block moved correctly to the heap by copy?

Comment: @Sulthan how do I check that?

Comment: How do you use it inside the method? You can also try to add `block = [block copy]` to see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the UI code must run in the main thread, you need to enclose your alert code in a `dispatch_async` block, like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!"
                                                 message:@"Online sync is now enabled."
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
    [av show];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I just tried that without any success. It is the same problem as before. The moment I click on OK, it crashes.

Comment: So it must be crashing somewhere in `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`. Have you checked that your `note` object is not nil?

Comment: Well, the crash is evidently in `FTLoginViewController connectToAccount:]`. I don't think the alert view is a problem here. Can you post the code for `connectToAccount`?

Comment: Yes thank you. I have updated the question with the entire method. I have a breakpoint on the first line of `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex` and it never gets there. So it crashes before hand.

Comment: It does't get to the delegate method because your delegate is set to nil. Speaking of which: if you set an object's delegate inside a block, don't use `self`. Create a weakSelf reference and use that. Let me know if that solves the problem!

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong `UIAlertView`. The first one is set to nil. That one is not called in my case though. It is the second one we are talking about, which has a delegate set. ;) I 'll try now the `weakSelf`.

Comment: Also, do you what is the line that causes the crash? Add an exception breakpoint to find out. It can really help debugging the issue. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I declared a `__weak FTLoginViewController *weakSelf;` and set it in `init` to `weakSelf = self;`  and used the `weakSelf` inside the block. Still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found out the problem.  As it was suggested it was a thread issue, which I couldn't discover first.

In the line:

```
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.hostReachability];
```

I was doing some work on an async thread, and at the end of that I called a

```
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This was happening while I was showing the popup and the two collided.  I removed the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` from the `updateInterfaceWithReachability` and put it into the delegate of the UIAlertView and now it works as expected.

I hope this helps others, with a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth considering is the memory management of the UIAlertView. If the UIAlertView is reallocated while visible, it will also cause a crash.